# How to color a part of a4j:commandLink text value?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, web-deployment, frontend

I want to color a part of `a4j:commandLink` text value
For example My target view
[image]

I use this code

```
<a4j:commandLink value="My Link  &lt;span style='color:red;'&gt;*&lt;/span&gt;"                         
    action="#{MyController.sort}">                          
</a4j:commandLink>
```

But I have that (undesired view)
[image]

Note
With `h:outputText` That have `escape` property
The text value will be colored

For Example
This code

```
<h:outputText value="My Text   &lt;span style='color:red;'&gt;*&lt;/span&gt;" 
escape="false"/>
```

Will produce this view
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just nest your `<span>` element inside your `<a4j:commandLink>` tag instead of using the `value` attribute. Use it like this:

```
<a4j:commandLink ...>
    <span>Plain text 
        <span class='red'>*</span>
    </span>
</a4j:commandLink>
```